# Linux mint 15, synaptic can't download all repository indexes

Tags: linux, synaptic

I'm using Linux Mint 15, and started getting these errors from synaptic update manager. I did not change anything in the system, one day it just started to throw these errors. My network works OK, all websites load without any problems. How can I track the cause of the issue?

[image: Synapctic error]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because [Ubuntu 13.04 has been end-of-lifed](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/01/28/ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail-end-of-life-reached-on-january-27-2014/) (Mint 15 was released [2013-05-29](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2366)).

If you absolutely **must** keep Mint 15, you will need to update `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` to point to the Ubuntu Archive URLs:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia main upstream import  #id:linuxmint_main
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring partner
```

The above also means that you will **not** recieve secrutiy updates or bug fixes for installed software, so you *should* update to the latest version.

The latest version of Linux Mint is Mint 17, which is based on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr). This is an LTS (Long Term Support) release, and will be supported until April 2019.

Answer (score 3):

Your system is trying to use repositories from Ubuntu 13.04, upon which Mint was apparently derived, and the error is occurring because those repositories are no longer present. They were removed after 13.04 went end of life, which was [some months ago](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life).

It's time to upgrade your system.

Comment: Will upgrade preserve my entire dev environment, mysql & postgres configuration and data, python virtualenvs, installed software etc.?

Comment: That's a trick question, right?

Comment: What's the point of releasing operating system in 2013 and stopping support in 2014? Makes little sense. Imagine microsoft did that lol.

Comment: Ubuntu does that with all their non-LTS releases, and has done since they started.

Comment: Yeah, now I know about LTS, but they also release these short-lived versions... If you're unaware of the fact and install them you're screwed a year later. Sigh...

Comment: True, Mint's web site doesn't make this very clear.